# Java ASM GeneratorAdapter variable naming

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am generating a simple class and unable to inject a proper variable name.
ASM version is `5.2`.

Here is the code:

```
package com.test;

import org.objectweb.asm.*;
import org.objectweb.asm.commons.GeneratorAdapter;
import org.objectweb.asm.commons.Method;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
        String name = "com.test.Sub";
        cw.visit(Opcodes.V1_8, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, name.replace('.', '/'), null, "java/lang/Object", null);
        Method ctor = Method.getMethod("void <init>()");
        GeneratorAdapter mg = new GeneratorAdapter(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, ctor, null, null, cw);
        mg.visitCode();
        mg.loadThis();
        mg.invokeConstructor(Type.getType(Object.class), ctor);
        int var = mg.newLocal(Type.INT_TYPE);
        mg.push(42.42);
        mg.storeLocal(var);
        Label varLabel = mg.mark();
        mg.returnValue();
        Label endLabel = mg.mark();
        mg.visitLocalVariable("x", "D", null, varLabel, endLabel, var);
        mg.endMethod();
        cw.visitEnd();
        byte[] bytes = cw.toByteArray();
        Files.write(Paths.get(name + ".class"), bytes);
    }

}
```

I am using a `GeneratorAdapter` to simplify code generation. Since `GeneratorAdapter` is inherited from `LocalVariablesSorter`, I assume that it is allowed to use `newLocal(Type)` method from it.

There is nothing wrong with the emitted bytecode except the name of the variable. When `visitLocalVariable()` method is called, instead of assigning a name to the variable it creates a new one in the bytecode.

Emitted bytecode:

```
// class version 52.0 (52)
// access flags 0x1
public class com/test/Sub {
  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>()V
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
    LDC 42.42
    DSTORE 1
   L0
    RETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE x D L0 L1 3
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 5
}
```

I am using the same variable index provided by `newLocal()` call in `visitLocalVariable()`. However in the bytecode mapped index is `3` instead of `1`. If the variable has a "shorter" type such as `int` then the index would be `2` and still not `1` as it should.

From my observations this happens because of the following. `LocalVariablesSorter` maintains a mapping from old variable indices to new ones. It also overrides method `visitLocalVariable` and before delegating a call down a visitor chain it computes a `newIndex` from the mapping. The `newIndex` is calculated via another private method `remap()`. This method checks whether the mapping already exists for a given variable and if not then a new mapping is created. The problem as I see it is that `newLocal()` method does not add anything to the mapping.

Also I can see from ASM sources that `storeInsn()` in `GeneratorAdapter` delegates `visitVarInsn()` call down the chain instead of calling the implementation of `LocalVariablesSorter`. Because it is in `LocalVariablesSorter` implementation the `remap()` method is called for the variable index and mapping is updated.

Therefore my question is how to use `GeneratorAdapter` so variables are named properly in emitted bytecode or how to combine `GeneratorAdapter` with `LocalVariablesSorter` in a chain so they work properly together?

Comment: Well, it’s the *purpose* of `LocalVariablesSorter` to modify the behavior of the subsequent `visit…` calls. Obviously, all operations that should not get altered, must bypass the `LocalVariablesSorter`, just like the methods introduced by `GeneratorAdapter` do.

Comment: Then why `GeneratorAdapter` is inherited from `LocalVariablesSorter` if it fails to provide functionality of the parent?

Comment: Don’t ask me, I'm not the one who made this decision. But where’s the problem in calling that method on the target visitor instead of the adapter?

Comment: The problem is that I do not use any other visitors, at least explicitly. I [derive](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/GeneratorAdapter.html#GeneratorAdapter-int-org.objectweb.asm.commons.Method-java.lang.String-org.objectweb.asm.Type:A-org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor-) my generator straight from `ClassWriter`. If you can explain how to build a valid chain of method visitors, please do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `GeneratorAdapter` extends `LocalVariablesSorter`, whose purpose is to adapt all visitor calls, all methods which are part of the visitor API get adapted, unlike the dedicated methods introduced by `GeneratorAdapter`. This design allows to insert new code into an existing method, where the old code gets reported through the visitor API.

So the method `visitLocalVariable`, which is part of the visitor API, must be called on the target `MethodVisitor`, bypassing the `LocalVariablesSorter`:

```
ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
String name = "com.test.Sub";
cw.visit(Opcodes.V1_8, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC,
         name.replace('.', '/'), null, "java/lang/Object", null);
Method ctor = Method.getMethod("void <init>()");
MethodVisitor direct = cw.visitMethod(
         Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, ctor.getName(), ctor.getDescriptor(), null, null);
GeneratorAdapter mg = new GeneratorAdapter(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, ctor, direct);
mg.visitCode();
mg.loadThis();
mg.invokeConstructor(Type.getType(Object.class), ctor);
int var = mg.newLocal(Type.DOUBLE_TYPE);
mg.push(42.42);
mg.storeLocal(var);
Label varLabel = mg.mark();
mg.returnValue();
Label endLabel = mg.mark();
direct.visitLocalVariable("x", "D", null, varLabel, endLabel, var);
mg.endMethod();
cw.visitEnd();
byte[] bytes = cw.toByteArray();
Files.write(Paths.get(name + ".class"), bytes);
```

Since this can be confusing, here the alternative directly working on the target `MethodVisitor` entirely without any convenience wrapper like `GeneratorAdapter`. It isn’t more complex, though it requires slightly more knowledge, however, it’s knowledge that developers should have anyway, when dealing with Java bytecode and class files…

```
ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
String name = "com.test.Sub";
String superClName = "java/lang/Object", ctorName = "<init>", ctorDesc = "()V";
cw.visit(Opcodes.V1_8, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, name.replace('.','/'), null, superClName, null);
MethodVisitor direct = cw.visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, ctorName, ctorDesc, null, null);
direct.visitCode();
// "this" is alway 0 (zero) and for parameterless methods the next var location is 1 (one)
int thisVar = 0, var = 1;
direct.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, thisVar);
direct.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL, superClName, ctorName, ctorDesc, false);
direct.visitLdcInsn(42.42);
Label varLabel = new Label(), endLabel = new Label();
direct.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.DSTORE, var);
direct.visitLabel(varLabel);
direct.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);
direct.visitLabel(endLabel);
direct.visitLocalVariable("x", "D", null, varLabel, endLabel, var);
direct.visitMaxs(-1, -1);// no actual values, using COMPUTE_FRAMES
direct.visitEnd();
cw.visitEnd();
byte[] bytes = cw.toByteArray();
Files.write(Paths.get(name + ".class"), bytes);
```

If you don’t feel comfortable with using `()V` for a parameterless `void` method directly, you could still use the `Method` object like before or [`Type.getMethodDescriptor(Type.VOID_TYPE)`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html#getMethodDescriptor-org.objectweb.asm.Type-org.objectweb.asm.Type...-)