# ASM - strange localVar index using newLocal from LocalVariableSorter

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, byte-buddy, jvm-bytecode

I'm adding new locals via `newLocal` from `LocalVariableSorter`. The method I'm adding the locals to is an instance method with a long parameter. I'm adding two locals; one long, one object. There are no other local vars in the sample code.

As a result I would have expected the following slots / indexes:

```
0 - this
1 - the long param
3 - my 1st local added via `newLocal` - using two slots as it is a long
5 - my 2nd local added via `newLocal`
```

What I do get as return from `newLocal` is 3 and 7 though. Why such a big gap?

And to make things even more strange, when I add `xSTORE` instructions using those indexes and check the result with javap it shows me:

```
LSTORE 5
ASTORE 8
```

Note: Not only are the values different then the ones I've passed to the xSTORE instruction, also the gap between them is now 3 instead of 4 as before.

The resulting code works though. I would just like to understand what *magic* is happening here an why.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your code? Also, are you sure you're not calling anything in between which would implicitly add locals? Try subclassing LocalVariableSorter and adding a print statement to `newLocal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LocalVariableSorter` class has a design, which makes it very easy to use it wrong.

When calling methods defined by the `MethodVisitor` API on it, the local variables undergo the renumbering mentioned in the [class documentation](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/commons/LocalVariablesSorter.html).

So when being used with a `ClassReader`, the visited old code gets transformed. Since you do not want the injected new code to undergo this transformation, but to use the newly defined variable(s), you have to bypass the `LocalVariableSorter` and call methods on the underlying target `MethodVisitor`.

When you call `visitVarInsn(LSTORE, 3)` on the `LocalVariableSorter`, it gets handled like an old instruction referring to index `3` and since you injected a new variable occupying index `3` and `4`, the “old variable” at index `3` gets remapped to the next free index, which is `5` (and `6`). Then, when you define your next new variable, it gets index `7` and calling `visitVarInsn(ASTORE, 7)` on the `LocalVariableSorter` is handled like an old variable which conflicts with your new variable, so it gets remapped to `8`.

This behavior matches exactly what the first sentence of the class documentation states:

##### [LocalVariablesSorter](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/commons/LocalVariablesSorter.html)

> A MethodVisitor that renumbers local variables in their order of appearance.

So while you have to call `newLocal` on the `LocalVariableSorter` to create a new variable that won’t get remapped, you have to call the `visit…` methods on the original, wrapped `MethodVisitor` to use it. When you use the subclass `GeneratorAdapter`, you can use its newly defined methods (those not starting with `visit…`) to create new instructions which don’t get transformed, but to me, this would make matters even worse, having methods for transforming instructions and creating untransformed instructions on the same class and always needing to keep in mind that the `visit…` prefix makes the difference. For some methods, you would still need to access the original method visitor, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45552419/2711488) which deals with `visitLocalVariable` to create debug information for the created variable.

Comment: Ah btw: Do you see any problems with not adjusting my code to call the `visit...` methods on the original, wrapped `MethodVisitor` but leave the gaps in the local counting? Although not being nice, it works. Just wondering if there could be any side effects.

Comment: This only works as long as the code you’re transforming doesn’t use these variables. The point is, you’ve reserved certain indices and the `LocalVariablesSorter` will remap the old code so it will not use these indices. When you’re using different indices you’re not only loosing this protection, you’re making the entire use of `LocalVariablesSorter` pointless. When you know beforehand, which indices are definitely unused, e.g. when generating entirely new code, you don’t need to use `LocalVariablesSorter` at all, you can just use these indices with a `MethodVisitor` returned by a `ClassWriter`