# Instrumentation at the start and end of method

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to add certain instructions at the beginning and end of methods in a jar.
Below is what i'm aiming to achieve in `SampleJar` class

#### `SampleJar.java`

```
package sample;
import snd_pkg.Sender;

public class SampleJar {

public static void func(){
    long l1=System.nanoTime(); //Instruction to be inserted
    /*
     * Existing instructions
     */
    long l2=System.nanoTime();  //Instruction to be inserted
    (new Sender()).send(l1,l2); //Instruction to be inserted
   }
}
```

#### `Sender.java`

```
package snd_pkg;

public class Sender {
 public  void send(long start,long stop)
   {
       //do something
   }
}
```

Below is what i've tried in `EntityModifier` class

#### `EntityModifier.java`

```
public class EtityModifier extends AdviceAdapter {


protected EtityModifier(int api, MethodVisitor methodVisitor, int access, String name, String descriptor) {
    super(api, methodVisitor, access, name, descriptor);
    
}

private final static int STARTIME_INDEX = 100;
private final static int STOPTIME_INDEX = 102;


@Override
protected void onMethodEnter() { 
    // Invoking the nanoTime method
    mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "java/lang/System", "nanoTime", "()J", false);
    // Storing long type value at STARTIME_INDEX
    mv.visitVarInsn(LSTORE, STARTIME_INDEX);
}

@Override
protected void onMethodExit(final int opcode) {
    if (opcode == RETURN || opcode == ARETURN || opcode == DRETURN || opcode == FRETURN || opcode == IRETURN
            || opcode == LRETURN) {
        // Invoking the nanoTime method
        mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "java/lang/System", "nanoTime", "()J", false);
        // Storing long type value in a local variable at STOPTIME_INDEX
        mv.visitVarInsn(LSTORE, STOPTIME_INDEX);
        // create Sender object
        mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "snd_pkg/Sender");
        // dup
        mv.visitInsn(DUP);
        // call Sender Constructor
        mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "snd_pkg/Sender", "<init>", "()V", false);
        // Loading startTime from STARTIME_INDEX
        mv.visitVarInsn(LLOAD, STARTIME_INDEX);
        // Loading stopTime from STOPTIME_INDEX
        mv.visitVarInsn(LLOAD, STOPTIME_INDEX);
        // call send Method
        mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "snd_pkg/Sender", "send", "(JJ)V", false);
    }
  }
}
```

I have an exe which calls the methods from `SampleJar` jar file during runtime, but after instrumentation the exe is failing to launch. The bytecode appears to be right. It's able to load  value from `STOPTIME_INDEX`, but **not** from `STARTIME_INDEX`.

Initially made use of **`LocalVariablesSorter.newLocal()`**, but there seems to be variable slot collision between variable index provided by **`newLocal()`**  with other existing local variables in method. Hence randomly assigned `STARTIME_INDEX` and `STOPTIME_INDEX` with 100 and 102 resp.

Error in log file:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad local variable type
Type top (current frame, locals[100]) is not assignable to long
```

There seems to be a problem retrieving value from `STARTIME_INDEX`.

Is there something wrong with this approach?

Comment: 1) Are you aware that `Long` is not the same as `long` and `Integer` not the same an `int`? Don’t use the wrapper types when not necessary. 2) Why are you defining *three* variables in your first example? 3) Since you assume the variable indices to be unused (which is questionable on its own), do you ensure that the new max variables are reflected in the class file (i.e. do you use `COMPUTE_MAX` or `COMPUTE_FRAMES`)? Showing your actual class visitor would help. 4) Regarding how to use `LocalVariablesSorter`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50150718/2711488) may help.

Comment: If you do not want to do this yourself with ASM, Byte Buddy `Advice` can change this byte code for you. Byte Buddy does neither require the use of `COMPUTE_FRAMES` what is a rather problematic and expensive option. Byte Buddy lets you implement this in plain Java and with likely better runtime performance. (For disclosure: I am the author of Byte Buddy.)

Comment: I support Rafael's suggestion and want to mention another option: AspectJ. I have used it for many years and am very happy with it. ByteBuddy is great too though, if you also need lower-level stuff and are not afraid of it. But probably you are not afraid, otherwise you would not be using ASM now.