# how to get maxLocals by core api in ASM?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I want to get `maxLocals` for storing data，like

```
int index = mv.visitLocalVariable(name, desc, null, start, end, ++maxLocals);
```

by `tree api` , `this.nextLocals = methodNode.maxLocals;`
but core api , nothing.

Inject into out , error method around biz~.

like this:

```java
@Test
    public void testCode() {
        hooK hook = StatisGet.get(1L);
        hook.into();
        try {
            //biz
            hook.out();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            hook.error(e);
        }
    }
```

now I am able to successfully inject bytecode, but solt sometimes gets wrong because I can't get maxLocal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming with “Core API” you mean the Visitor API, there is the method [`visitMaxs`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitMaxs-int-int-) on the `MethodVisitor`, which will be invoked with the maximum stack and local variable numbers.

But there is a catch; this method will be invoked *after* the other visitor methods. So you can’t use that number beforehand to find an unused local variable.

A solution is to use an adapter, the [`LocalVariablesSorter`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/?org/objectweb/asm/commons/LocalVariablesSorter.html), if you consider it to be part of the “Core API”. It allows you to invoke [`newLocal`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/commons/LocalVariablesSorter.html#newLocal-org.objectweb.asm.Type-) when you need a free local variable and it will tell you the next variable number that has not been encountered so far. It will then remember the number and if encountering conflicting variable number uses when continuing to visit the original code, it will renumber those variable numbers, to solve the conflict.

You only have to care to invoke the visitor methods on the original method visitor (the writer) when dealing with your injected code, as the visitor methods on the [`LocalVariablesSorter`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/?org/objectweb/asm/commons/LocalVariablesSorter.html) will be invoked for the original code and transformed. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50150718/2711488) and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45552419/2711488).